# How to download historical-data (csv format) from investing.com with Puppeteer Js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I tried this piece of code to download historical data in csv format from investing.com.

```
//collector.mjs
import puppeteer from "puppeteer";
import path from "path";

(async ()=>{
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.setUserAgent('Chrome/105.0.0.0');

  await page.goto("https://www.investing.com/equities/tesla-motors-historical-data", {
    waitUntil: "networkidle2",
  });

  const client = await page.target().createCDPSession();
  await client .send('Page.setDownloadBehavior', {
    behavior: 'allow',
    downloadPath: path.resolve("./csvData"),
  });

  await page.evaluate(()=>{
    document.querySelector("span[class='download-data_text__Myrn3']").click();
  });

  await browser.close();
})();
```

What i get all the time is "TSLA Historical Data.csv.crdownload" file (instead).

[image]

So, how to get this (picture under) instead in my folder csvData?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the page.setViewport().

```
//collector.mjs
import puppeteer from "puppeteer";
import path from "path";

(async ()=>{
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.setUserAgent('Chrome/105.0.0.0');

  await page.setViewport({
    width: 1920,
    height: 1080
  });

  await page.goto("https://www.investing.com/equities/tesla-motors-historical-data", {
    waitUntil: "networkidle2",
  });

  const client = await page.target().createCDPSession();
  await client .send('Browser.setDownloadBehavior', {
    behavior: 'allow',
    downloadPath: path.resolve("./csvData"),
  });

  await page.click('.download-data_text__Myrn3');

  await browser.close();
})();
```

Done,